# Converting the stream of bytes into 32 bit unsigned integer

Tags: c, serialization, deserialization

I think this code is converting the stream of bytes into 32 bit unsigned integer. But what's the use of double pointer (**buf). Can't we use simply a single pointer?
Could somebody explain me how does this code snippet work with an example?

```
uint32_t unpack_u32(const uint8_t **buf) {
    uint32_t val;
    memcpy(&val, *buf, sizeof(uint32_t));
    (*buf) += sizeof(uint32_t);
    return ntohl(val);
}
```

Comment: I would personally instead of `sizeof(uint32_t);` use `sizeof(val);`

Answer (score 1):

The API is for use in repeated form. The pointer in the buffer is increased to the next unpacked data.

```
uint8_t *buf = ...
uint32_t first = unpack_u32(&buf);
uint16_t second = unpack_u16(&buf);
uint32_t third = unpack_u32(&buf);
```

Comment: Yes, it is the `(*buf) += sizeof(uint32_t);` line in `unpack_u32()` that shifts the pointer over `sizeof(uint32_t)` bytes.